# What's the difference between Cache-Control: max-age=0 and no-cache?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

The header `Cache-Control: max-age=0` implies that the content is considered stale (and must be re-fetched) immediately, which is in effect the same thing as `Cache-Control: no-cache`.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

Answer (score 677, accepted):

I had this same question, and found some info in my searches (your question came up as one of the results).  Here's what I determined...

There are two sides to the `Cache-Control` header.  One side is where it can be sent by the web server (aka. "origin server").  The other side is where it can be sent by the browser (aka. "user agent").

---

### When sent by the origin server

I believe `max-age=0` simply tells caches (and user agents) the response is stale from the get-go and so they **SHOULD** revalidate the response (eg. with the `If-Not-Modified` header) before using a cached copy, whereas, `no-cache` tells them they **MUST** revalidate before using a cached copy.  From [14.9.1 What is Cacheable](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1):

> **no-cache**
>
> ...a cache MUST NOT use the response
>   to satisfy a subsequent request
>   without successful revalidation with
>   the origin server.  This allows an
>   origin server to prevent caching even
>   by caches that have been configured to
>   return stale responses to client
>   requests.

In other words, caches may sometimes choose to use a stale response (although I believe they have to then add a `Warning` header), but `no-cache` says they're not allowed to use a stale response no matter what.  Maybe you'd want the **SHOULD**-revalidate behavior when baseball stats are generated in a page, but you'd want the **MUST**-revalidate behavior when you've generated the response to an e-commerce purchase.

Although you're correct in your comment when you say `no-cache` is not supposed to prevent storage, it might actually be another difference when using `no-cache`.  I came across a page, [Cache Control Directives Demystified](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811162719/http://palizine.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/), that says (I can't vouch for its correctness):

> In practice, IE and Firefox have
>   started treating the no-cache
>   directive as if it instructs the
>   browser not to even cache the page. 
>   We started observing this behavior
>   about a year ago.  We suspect that
>   this change was prompted by the
>   widespread (and incorrect) use of this
>   directive to prevent caching.
>
> ...
>
> Notice that of late, "cache-control:
>   no-cache" has also started behaving
>   like the "no-store" directive.

As an aside, it appears to me that `Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate` should basically mean the same thing as `Cache-Control: no-cache`.  So maybe that's a way to get the **MUST**-revalidate behavior of `no-cache`, while avoiding the apparent migration of `no-cache` to doing the same thing as `no-store` (ie. no caching whatsoever)?

---

### When sent by the user agent

I believe [shahkalpesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1046987) applies to the user agent side.  You can also look at [13.2.6 Disambiguating Multiple Responses](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.6).

If a user agent sends a request with `Cache-Control: max-age=0` (aka. "end-to-end revalidation"), then each cache along the way will revalidate its cache entry (eg. with the `If-Not-Modified` header) all the way to the origin server.  If the reply is then 304 (Not Modified), the cached entity can be used.

On the other hand, sending a request with `Cache-Control: no-cache` (aka. "end-to-end reload") doesn't revalidate and the server **MUST NOT** use a cached copy when responding.

Comment: Wouldn't Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate would be the exact equivalence of no-cache ?

Comment: Great answer, I went to read the article you site but the page is no longer valid.  http://palisade.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/

Comment: Thanks, @CraigLondon.  I redirected it to a cached version.

Comment: [Section 14.9.4 Cache Revalidation and Reload Controls, HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4) describes `max-age=0` and `no-cache` quite well.

Comment: There is a reference about the differences here...  https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#no-cache_and_no-store

Comment: `must-revalidate` is NOT meant to be the same as `no-cache` or `no-store`. The latter bypass caches altogether, but the former just says that a cache must always be checked for freshness, but if it is still current, it can be used, so saving bandwidth. The latter forces full end-to-end downloads all the time, taking up unnecessary bandwidth and delaying responses.

Comment: @DidierA. I would say `max-age=0` makes only 1 real request if you trigger two HTTP requests at the exact same time while `must-revalidate` should always trigger 2 requests. But the showcase will be very hard to set up!

Comment: @Patanjali `no-cache` *doesn't* "bypass caches altogether" or "force full end-to-end downloads all the time", at least not in all browsers. [The specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.2) only says that browser must validate the cache.

Comment: @FranklinYu. Yes, specifically `no-cache` does only ask for revalidation, rather than full re-download, so it does involve a round-trip latency, but not a bandwidth hit. Because it allows a field-name list, it does seem to be designed as a mechanism for partial caching. The `no-store` only talks about preventing non-volatile memory storage, so in-memory caching is still OK. Pays to read the spec, because the terms don't really convey what their words really mean.

Comment: @Patanjali I know, so how is that helping this question? `must-revalidate` with `max-age=0` still looks the same as `no-cache`. I was targeting your claim "`must-revalidate` is NOT meant to be the same as `no-cache` or `no-store`", and the `no-cache` part (because I know about `no-store`).

Comment: What would happen if no Cache-Control header is found? Will the browser just not cache the response? Does different browser has different behavior in this case?

Comment: `max-age=0` and `no-cache` would result in different behaviour when `max-stale` request directive is used. with a `max-stale` request directive user would be able to get a stale response from the cache if the server ONLY sent `max-age=0`. But with `no-cache`, cache MUST revalidate before returning the cached response, no matter how fresh/stale the item is.

Comment: The language for `must-revalidate` is also similar in the sense that cache waits for the item to expire (become stale). After that it has to re-validate. Until then, it can be served and `max-stale` from the user can extend the time it can be served without validation

Comment: But something is strange, `Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate` can return 304 in Firefox with `ETag/If-None-Match`, but always return 200 in Chrome, do you know the reason?

Comment: People who understand what "must revalidate the cache" means probably already know what no-cache, no-store, max-age do.  I don't.  I am here because I want to know which option in a request header will force to go all the way to the server and request the resource regardless of any cache state or header or what.

Answer (score 57):

**max-age=0**

This is equivalent to clicking *Refresh*, which means, give me the latest copy unless I already have the latest copy.

**no-cache**

This is holding *Shift* while clicking Refresh, which means, just redo everything no matter what.

Comment: This is incorrect. shift-refresh is a hard refresh which is more similar to `no-store`

Comment: Verified in Firefox 45.0 which, like Chrome 49.0.2623.87 m, also sends a "Pragma: no-cache" when Shift+Refreshing.

Comment: Your description is inaccurate.  This is misinforming people.

Answer (score 37):

Old question now, but if anyone else comes across this through a search as I did, it appears that IE9 will be making use of this to configure the behaviour of resources when using the back and forward buttons. When *max-age=0* is used, the browser will use the last version when viewing a resource on a back/forward press.  If *no-cache* is used, the resource will be refetched.

Further details about IE9 caching can be seen on this [msdn caching blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx).

Comment: Similarly, IE 8 runs into all sorts of "could not download" issues when no-cache is used over https.  suggested resolutions sometimes include changing headers to max-age=0

Answer (score 31):

In my recent tests with IE8 and Firefox 3.5, it seems that both are RFC-compliant. However, they differ in their "friendliness" to the origin server. IE8 treats `no-cache` responses with the same semantics as `max-age=0,must-revalidate`. Firefox 3.5, however, seems to treat `no-cache` as equivalent to `no-store`, which sucks for performance and bandwidth usage.

Squid Cache, by default, seems to never store anything with a `no-cache` header, just like Firefox.

My advice would be to set `public,max-age=0` for non-sensitive resources you want to have checked for freshness on every request, but still allow the performance and bandwidth benefits of caching. For per-user items with the same consideration, use `private,max-age=0`.

I would avoid the use of `no-cache` entirely, as it seems it has been bastardized by some browsers and popular caches to the functional equivalent of `no-store`.

Additionally, do not emulate Akamai and Limelight. While they essentially run massive caching arrays as their primary business, and should be experts, they actually have a vested interest in causing more data to be downloaded from their networks. Google might not be a good choice for emulation, either. They seem to use `max-age=0` or `no-cache` randomly depending on the resource.

Comment: Best answer for password protected content. `private,max-age=0`.

Answer (score 23):

```
max-age
    When an intermediate cache is forced, by means of a max-age=0 directive, to revalidate 
its own cache entry, and the client has supplied its own validator in the request, the 
supplied validator might differ from the validator currently stored with the cache entry. 
In this case, the cache MAY use either validator in making its own request without 
affecting semantic transparency. 

    However, the choice of validator might affect performance. The best approach is for the 
intermediate cache to use its own validator when making its request. If the server replies 
with 304 (Not Modified), then the cache can return its now validated copy to the client 
with a 200 (OK) response. If the server replies with a new entity and cache validator, 
however, the intermediate cache can compare the returned validator with the one provided in 
the client's request, using the strong comparison function. If the client's validator is 
equal to the origin server's, then the intermediate cache simply returns 304 (Not 
Modified). Otherwise, it returns the new entity with a 200 (OK) response. 

    If a request includes the no-cache directive, it SHOULD NOT include min-fresh, 
max-stale, or max-age.
```

courtesy: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4

Don't accept this as answer - I will have to read it to understand the true usage of it :)

Comment: I actually tried to read that very page and didn't understand it.  I came to stackoverflow in hope for a simple, clear answer.

Answer (score 16):

I'm hardly a caching expert, but Mark Nottingham is. Here are his [caching docs](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/). He also has excellent links in the References section.

Based on my reading of those docs, it looks like `max-age=0` could allow the cache to send a cached response to requests that came in at the "same time" where "same time" means close enough together they look simultaneous to the cache, but `no-cache` would not.

Comment: Good point, but in practice does any browsers actually do that?

Comment: @Pacerier I think this is more for caching proxy servers like Varnish, Squid, Traffic, etc.

Answer (score 15):

By the way, it's worth noting that some mobile devices, particularly Apple products like iPhone/iPad completely ignore headers like no-cache, no-store, Expires: 0, or whatever else you may try to force them to not re-use expired form pages.

This has caused us no end of headaches as we try to get the issue of a user's iPad say, being left asleep on a page they have reached through a form process, say step 2 of 3, and then the device totally ignores the store/cache directives, and as far as I can tell, simply takes what is a virtual snapshot of the page from its last state, that is, ignoring what it was told explicitly, and, not only that, taking a page that should not be stored, and storing it without actually checking it again, which leads to all kinds of strange Session issues, among other things.

I'm just adding this in case someone comes along and can't figure out why they are getting session errors with particularly iphones and ipads, which seem by far to be the worst offenders in this area.

I've done fairly extensive debugger testing with this issue, and this is my conclusion, the devices ignore these directives completely.

Even in regular use, I've found that some mobiles also totally fail to check for new versions via say, Expires: 0 then checking last modified dates to determine if it should get a new one.

It simply doesn't happen, so what I was forced to do was add query strings to the css/js files I needed to force updates on, which tricks the stupid mobile devices into thinking it's a file it does not have, like: my.css?v=1, then v=2 for a css/js update. This largely works.

User browsers also, by the way, if left to their defaults, as of 2016, as I continuously discover (we do a LOT of changes and updates to our site) also fail to check for last modified dates on such files, but the query string method fixes that issue. This is something I've noticed with clients and office people who tend to use basic normal user defaults on their browsers, and have no awareness of caching issues with css/js etc, almost invariably fail to get the new css/js on change, which means the defaults for their browsers, mostly MSIE / Firefox, are not doing what they are told to do, they ignore changes and ignore last modified dates and do not validate, even with Expires: 0 set explicitly.

This was a good thread with a lot of good technical information, but it's also important to note how bad the support for this stuff is in particularly mobile devices. Every few months I have to add more layers of protection against their failure to follow the header commands they receive, or to properly interpet those commands.

Comment: css and js are suitable candidates for caching, as in production systems, they shouldn't really change often. However, having caching for them while developing is a pain, as that activity can require frequent forced cache-flushes. But, if one cannot use different settings for the different environments, production requirements should take precedent, as it has the most effect because the far larger numbers of accesses will save bandwidth, compared to the few Ctrl-F5 refreshes that a few developers will have to do. However, querying real-time data requires that cache-control work properly.

Answer (score 7):

This is answered directly in the [MDN docs about cache control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#up-to-date_contents_always):

> Most HTTP/1.0 caches don't support `no-cache` directives, so
> historically `max-age=0` was used as a workaround. But only
> `max-age=0` could cause a [stale response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#freshness) to be reused when caches
> disconnected from the origin server. `must-revalidate` addresses that.
> That's why the example below is equivalent to `no-cache`.
>
> ```
> Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
> ```
>
> But for now, you can simply use `no-cache` instead.

And also in the [MDN docs about cache validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#validation):

> It is often stated that the combination of `max-age=0` and
> `must-revalidate` has the same meaning as `no-cache`.
>
> ```
> Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
> ```
>
> `max-age=0` means that the
> response is immediately stale, and `must-revalidate` means that it must
> not be reused without revalidation once it is stale — so in
> combination, the semantics seem to be the same as `no-cache`.
>
> However, that usage of `max-age=0` is a remnant of the fact that many
> implementations prior to HTTP/1.1 were unable to handle the `no-cache`
> directive — and so to deal with that limitation, `max-age=0` was used as
> a workaround.
>
> But now that HTTP/1.1-conformant servers are widely deployed, there's
> no reason to ever use that `max-age=0`-and-`must-revalidate` combination —
> you should instead just use `no-cache`.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the added docs. There's a dupe copy of this question (it seems) that I found first and I literally just wrote a virtually identical [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72575381/616460) (great minds...). But then I found this and saw your answer, so I figured I'd just expand on yours instead of posting yet another answer. I think it's a useful addition, but nbd if you want to roll back.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that (surprisingly) hasn't been mentioned is that a request can explicitly indicate that it will accept stale data, using the `max-stale` directive. In that case, if the server responded with `max-age=0`, the cache would merely consider the response stale, and would be free to use it to satisfy the client's request [which asked for potentially-stale data]. By contrast, if the server sends `no-cache` that really does trump any request by the client (with `max-stale`) for stale data, as the cache MUST revalidate.