# Understand If-Modified-Since HTTP Header

Tags: php, http, cache-control, outputcache, if-modified-since

I am looking at a Caching library that is trying to use the `If-Modified-Since` header of a request object. The problem is this header never gets set, it is always blank which makes sense to me seeing how it is a REQUEST.

How can you force a request to have a `If-Modified-Since` header? Or am I way off for what this does.

Here is the function I am referring to.

```
public function isNotModified(Request $request)
{
    $lastModified = $request->headers->get('If-Modified-Since');

    $notModified = false;
    if ($etags = $request->getEtags()) {
        $notModified = (in_array($this->getEtag(), $etags) || in_array('*', $etags)) && (!$lastModified || $this->headers->get('Last-Modified') == $lastModified);
    } elseif ($lastModified) {
        $notModified = $lastModified == $this->headers->get('Last-Modified');
    }

    if ($notModified) {
        $this->setNotModified();
    }

    return $notModified;
}
```

Comment: How can you force a *request* to have *anything*?

Answer (score 26):

A request with [`If-Modified-Since`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) only makes sense if the client already has a resource which is obtained along with a response that has a [`Last-Modified`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) header in combination with headers which allow browser caching like a [`Cache-Control`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) and/or [`Pragma`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32) value containing `public`.

Also, I've noticed that some browsers does not include `If-Modified-Since` when the original response also contained an [`ETag`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19) header. The browser will instead use [`If-None-Match`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26) to test it.

#### See also:

- [Caching tutorial for web authors and web masters](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)

Comment: @symc: which is still very valid in combination with some old proxies. It's only beyond me how mentioning that would potentially influence the OP's concrete issue negatively :) Have had a bad day?

Answer (score 13):

First you have to make sure the initial response is cached in the first place (I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017454/make-ie-to-cache-resources-but-always-revalidate) this in another, related question.

Try to set the following fields:

```
Last-Modified: Wed, 16 Feb 2011 13:52:26 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, private
```

- `Last-Modified` is needed as a validator (do not send `ETag` if you want to test for `If-Modified-Since`)
- `Expires -1` tells that the resource is stale and must always be revalidated
- `Cache-Control` must not include no-cache nor no-store

When you send these headers on the initial `HTTP/200` response, on subsequent requests, the browser should send conditional requests that include the `If-Modified-Since` header.

Comment: What if I always want to process the 'content'?  Is there a way to get the 'cached' data?