# Understand Etags HTTP Header

Tags: php, http, outputcache, cache-control

I am using a caching library that has the function seen below. It is attempting to grab eTags from the Request on the 5th line but the eTags are never set.

When would a REQUEST have eTags? and how might you set them?

Thanks.

```
public function isNotModified(Request $request)
{
    $lastModified = $request->headers->get('If-Modified-Since');

    $notModified = false;
    if ($etags = $request->getEtags()) {
        $notModified = (in_array($this->getEtag(), $etags) || in_array('*', $etags)) && (!$lastModified || $this->headers->get('Last-Modified') == $lastModified);
    } elseif ($lastModified) {
        $notModified = $lastModified == $this->headers->get('Last-Modified');
    }

    if ($notModified) {
        $this->setNotModified();
    }

    return $notModified;
}
```

Comment: [ETag](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19) if only a response header field: “The ETag response-header field provides the current value of the entity tag for the requested variant.”

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081397/understand-if-modified-since-http-header And indeed, `ETag` appears in response header only. The contra-header in requests is `If-None-Match`, as answered in your other question.

Answer (score 2):

The [*ETag* header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19) is for responses only:

> The *ETag* response-header field provides the current value of the entity tag for the requested variant.

But the `getEtags` method could be the tags from the [*If-None-Match* header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26):

> If any of the entity tags match the entity tag of the entity that would have been returned in the response to a similar GET request (without the *If-None-Match* header) on that resource, or if "`*`" is given and any current entity exists for that resource, then the server MUST NOT perform the requested method, unless required to do so because the resource's modification date fails to match that supplied in an *If-Modified-Since* header field in the request. Instead, if the request method was GET or HEAD, the server SHOULD respond with a 304 (Not Modified) response, including the cache- related header fields (particularly *ETag*) of one of the entities that matched. For all other request methods, the server MUST respond with a status of 412 (Precondition Failed).

This seems to match the given code exactly (I rearranged the first sentence to fit the code):

```
//   the server MUST NOT perform the requested method
$notModified = (
    //   if any of the entity tags match the entity tag of the entity that
    //   would have been returned in the response to a similar GET request
    //   (without the If-None-Match header) on that resource
    in_array($this->getEtag(), $etags)
    //   or if "*" is given and any current entity exists for that resource
    || in_array('*', $etags))
    //   unless required to do so because the resource's modification
    //   date fails to match that supplied in an If-Modified-Since header
    //   field in the request.
    && (!$lastModified || $this->headers->get('Last-Modified') == $lastModified);
```

The last expression `(!$lastModified || $this->headers->get('Last-Modified') == $lastModified)` is equivalent to `!($lastModified && $this->headers->get('Last-Modified') != $lastModified)` that fits the last sentence part better.

Comment: it is checking the if_none_match header. This is a lot more confusing than i thought it would be. I just want to CACHE!

Comment: @Mike: if all you want is forcing the browser to cache the resource, just add `ETag`, `Last-Modified` and `Expires` headers to the **response** of the resource. Then, when a subsequent request comes in with `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match`, just test them and handle accordingly by returning 304 or the changed resource in question.