# Internet Explorer vs. Chrome Cache

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, browser-cache

Basically, I am trying to make my website more user-friendly by enabling caching.  To test my progress, I am using the developer tools in Chrome & IE with the end goal of minimizing the number of calls to the web server.  When chrome caches something, the developed tools will give a request response of **200 (cached)**.  On the other hand, IE will always send a small request to the server and get a **304 Response** before it reads from its cache.

Which browser is properly following HTTP, and if the answer is Chrome, how can I eliminate the unnecessary 304 calls in IE?

Comment: It depends on the caching-headers your server sends in order to say which browser is behaving correctly. Would help a lot if you add an example to your questions.

That said, Chrome is known to be a bit more aggressive in regards of caching than other browsers.

Comment: Having this same issue with IE 11.  All static content is fetched via a 304 response in IE 11, but Chrome hitting the same site returns all static content as 200 (from cache).  I want IE 11 to behave the same way as Chrome, but no matter what Expires information is in the header IE 11 insists on doing a 304.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be clear:

- **304** - Server response indicating resource not modified since last
  request
- **200** - Server response indicating resource returned
  successfully
- **200(cached)** - Psuedo browser response indicating item loaded
  from local cache

There are also subtle differences depending on how you reload/refresh the page, particularly for IE. (Do you click refresh button, or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the url bar?)  See following:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/07/08/technical-information-about-conditional-http-requests-and-the-refresh-button.aspx
- [What is the difference between HTTP status code 200 (cache) vs status code 304?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665082/http-status-code-200-cache-vs-status-code-304)

Comment: Randomly started working.  I notices that using F5 will send the 304 requests while pressing enter in the address bar will use the cache.  What WAS HAPPENING was chrome would properly cache and submit 19 requests while IE would ALWAYS do the 304 and do around 28 requests for my test page.  Now IE is actually making only 14 requests.  No idea why it randomly started working other than maybe I was pressing F5 the entire time.

Answer (score 2):

IE has some particular behavior involving cacheing. Arguably not incorrect, but different than the other browsers. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017454/make-ie-to-cache-resources-but-always-revalidate%20this%20post) for more info.

One technique, which is not following best practice (!), would be to make sure your expire dates are a healthy time in the future, and to not send last-modified to IE. Then IE will not send the if-modified-since request, but instead will only send requests when the cache has expired. In that case it will get a new document (200) instead of a 304. This new document should set the expires date a healthy time in the future. thus eliminating many requests by using the cached version which has an expired date in the future.

the if-modified-since requests are the heart of your 304 responses. The 304 responses are correct if the document has not been modified since the time IE is sending. The problem is that if your expired time is in the past, ie will always make this request (making a call to the server every time!).. and will never get a new expires date. so it will just keep making the same call and your server will keep replying with the same 304 response.

I am guessing that chrome is not a problem for you in terms of the number of requests to the server. if it is, can you better explain the number of requests you are seeing in both browsers, and the flow?