# IE 11 ignoring Cache Control header in response

Tags: tomcat, caching, cache-control, expires-header

I am setting Expires filter in web.xml of Tomcat. The header comes correctly in response but still IE is not caching. It is always making the fresh request to Tomcat.

```
<filter>
<filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>ExpiresByType image/png</param-name>
<param-value>access plus 2 hours</param-value>
</init-param>

</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Below are the headers from respone

Cache-Control:  max-age=7199

Expires:    Mon, 14 Nov 2016 16:08:22 GMT

Content-Type:   image/png

Transfer-Encoding:  chunked

Date:   Mon, 14 Nov 2016 14:08:22 GMT

Does anyone know, what am I missing here?

Comment: What about other browsers?

Comment: It works fine in other browsers.

Comment: I'm shocked, *shocked* that MSIE is behaving differently, here.

Answer (score 5):

There is [Microsoft's own documentation on cache-control](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/234067).

Short answer: you have to use `Pragma: no-cache`, `Cache-Control: no-cache` and `Expires` all together.

**Update 2019-01-24**

The above instructions are for *disabling* caching, while the answer to being able to *force* caching can be found in this fine SO answer:
[Make IE to cache resources but always revalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017454/make-ie-to-cache-resources-but-always-revalidate)

Comment: The question is about making IE cache the response. You link to a page "How to prevent caching in Internet Explorer", which is the opposite.