# Can browser caching be controlled by HTTP headers alone w/o using hash names for asset files?

Tags: http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control, http-caching

I'm reading it in [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#the-problem):

> The way it works has a pitfall: if we don’t change filenames of our resources when deploying a new version, browser might think it hasn’t been updated and client will get a cached version of it.

I'm curious, is it mandatory to use this mechanism with ugly file names `main.55e783391098c2496a8f.js` for assets in order to inform a browser that an asset file has changed?

Can it be controlled by HTTP headers only? There are multiple HTTP headers in the standard to control how browser caches assets, like:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2020 18:32:02 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 2024 12:45:26 GMT
ETag: x234dff
max-age: 12345
```

So can I use those headers alone? Or do I still have to bother about hash parts in file names `main.55e783391098c2496a8f.js`?

Answer (score 0):

When user agent opens a page it must always get correct version of a source code. You have two options to achieve this:

- Set `Cache-Control`, `Expires` and strong validator (`ETag`) response headers . This way you instruct user agent to perform relatively lightweight conditional request on each page load
- Embed version in source code file URL and set `Cache-Control` and `Expires` response headers. This way you instruct user agent to cache source code with particural version forever

For more information check [HTTP Caching article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) by Ilya Grigorik, [HTTP conditional requests MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Conditional_requests) and this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5084395/2594597) about resource revalidation.