# Browser keeps rendering its cached version. I want to always force a GET

Tags: html, caching, browser

How do I prevent the client browser from rendering its cached version for a page, so that it must always perform a GET when the visitor visits the page?

I am using Django's @never_cache decorator in the view, which adds "Cache-Control:max-age=0" to the HTTP GET header. However when I visit the page (in Google Chrome and Firefox, the only browsers I have tested so far), the cached version is inevitably rendered. (Confirmed by visiting the Network tab for the request, which reports "**200 OK (from cache)**".)

If I now click the Refresh button, it will render the *fresh* content from the server (Network tab for the request says "**200 OK**" and the headers as shown below.)

In lieu of setting "Cache-Control:max-age=0" I also tried setting the "Expires" HTTP header parameter to be a date in the past. This did not work either.

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
If-Modified-Since:Fri, 17 Feb 2012 15:25:21 GMT
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11

Response Headers
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 17 Feb 2012 15:55:11 GMT
ETag:"[removed]"
Expires:Fri, 17 Feb 2012 15:55:11 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 17 Feb 2012 15:55:11 GMT
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encodindg:chunked
Vary:Cookie,Accept-Encoding
X-Handled-By:127.0.0.1:8000
```

Comment: Does using "no-cache" instead fix the issue? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache not sure how to set that from Django though.

Comment: I haven't tried that. Doing so now...

Comment: That did not work, Graham. I set the Cache-Control header to "no-cache" and still Chrome delivers the cached version of the page, preventing the GET request. Again, I can click Chrome's Refresh button at this point to get the fresh content -- but naturally I want to prevent users from having to do that.

Comment: I should note that StackOverflow appears to have a similar problem. After I clicked the red "1" in the header to read Graham's comment, I clicked the link he shared which redirected me to another page -- and even though I had already read his message I saw the red "1" in the header. I assumed it was a new message, so clicked the "1" again but no one else had commented. The "1" disappeared (again) and after I had finished reading the page I clicked Chrome's back button -- and there was the "1" in the header again. I clicked it again, but there were no new messages for me to read.

Comment: This is only tangentially related to your problem, but you can't count on the browser to refresh **any** content when you click the Back button. WebKit caches entire pages, DOM and all, so that clicking back and forth through your history will immediately load previously visited pages. See [this article on the WebKit page cache](http://www.webkit.org/blog/427/webkit-page-cache-i-the-basics/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your response set these:

```
response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate' 
response['Expires'] = 'Fri, 01 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT'
```

It's how Google Docs enforces pages refresh at all times.

Then you can play with it to find the ideal behaviour for your purposes.

Comment: I can see that this is forcing chrome to request the page from my server, but it doesn't look like it is rendering the HTML that is returned. Specifically, I have a value that gets added to an attribute on save. When I hit the back button, I see that chrome requested the page again, but when I inspect the element, the value isn't added. When I view the source however, I see that the value has been correctly added to the element.

On Firefox everything is working properly.

Comment: @wildehahn Firefox works a bit differently - it supports back-forward cache. Not sure what the problem is here but maybe bf cache causes the difference you observe.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this in your htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|gif|html|jpg|js|php|png)$">
Header set Cache-Control: "max-age=0, no-store"
</FilesMatch>
```

You can adjust the files match line for a specific page/path and also for specific assets