# What is the effect of max-age=0 for load speed optimisation?

Tags: performance, caching, browser-cache, pagespeed

In terms of load speed optimisation, is `Cache-Control: max-age=0` with an 
`If-Modified-Since` date a problem? My browser reports a 304, but tools like Google's PageSpeed and YSlow flag them as a problem on account of the short (non-existent) "freshness lifetime".

I've read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache) and some of the linked resources but, while helpful, I'm still not clear on the net effect (if any) for load speed.

Many thanks.

Comment: 304 means the client browser still goes over the internet to validate the content and the webserver still needs to respond to and process the request to decide to do a 304 or a content-based 200 response.  These are hard delays which impact load speeds.  If the content has a (validly) defined life then the browser can optimise this all away and fetch the data from a local cache -- which is normally far faster.

Comment: @TerryE Ah, thank you, I think I see. I think I was expecting it not to cache at all, whereas in fact it is caching but the short max-age means the browser always has to check the server. So with a longer max-age, I'd see a 200 (from cache). Have I got that right?

Comment: Use the firebug or equiv Chrome / IE ... dev toolkit to instrument the client end and see what is going on. The [Google Pagespeed best practices](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro) are a mine of useful info to help you get up to speed.  And yes to your Q the longer the max-age, the longer that the browser will go directly to its local cache.