# How can I make page reload everytime I open it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making kind of social website. And i make a post edit page. The problem is when i finish edit post and click 'SAVE EDIT'. i use
`window.location='post_info.php?post_id='+postid;` on AJAX to go back to post info page.
But it appear to be old content from cache. 
question is what should i do to make my new post info appear immediatly when open it.

Comment: Use AJAX. With such a vague question, you can't expect a more detailed answer.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Asynchronous JavaScript and XML (AJAX) - have a look at google how it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

you should try this:

**Use Category: Shorthand Methods:** AJAX  [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/)

Comment: "want to reload page only once when start."
This will refresh the page not only once when start

Answer (score -1):

You just need to set the cache control HTTP headers for your HTML document so that the document is always loaded from the server and not the browser (or proxy) cache.

You can't do this with JavaScript or HTML (meta http-equiv is a joke), you need to set real HTTP headers.

Either

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

or

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

should get you what you want. See [this answer for an explanation of the differences between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache) and [Mnot's caching tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) for a more in depth look at caching and HTTP.

You can set these with a server side programming language (e.g. Perl, Python or PHP) or by configuring the web server directly. The specifics depend on which of those you choose.

Answer (score -2):

Change your code to

```
window.location='post_info.php?post_id='+postid+"&"+ new Date().getTime();
```