# express view cache acting funny

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm running into some funny stuff with the view cache in express/Jade. The controller fetches an article from MongoDB via Mongoose and hands it to the res.render function. However, after running for a couple of minutes Express starts serving the same compiled template for all requests to that route. This even happens to shared .jade includes that are used in various templates.

The database is fetching the correct articles and it doesn't matter if I pass some random strings to the template, I always get the same output.

This is the controller function:

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
  var articleId;
  articleId = req.params.id;
  Article.findOne({
    _id: articleId
  }).populate('author').exec(function(err, article) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render('articles/show', {
        article: article,
        articleId: article.id
      });
    }
  });
};
```

And that's the route:

```
app.get('/articles/:id', articles.show);
```

The same things happen whether I'm running in production or development mode.

Has anyone run into this kind of toruble with Express/Jade?

Comment: With "the same compiled template", do you mean the same *rendered* template? I'm not sure it's the view cache, since that's not active when run in dev mode (unless you explicitly enabled it?). Also, the view cache only stores compiled (but unrendered) templates, they will still be rendered separately for each request. What does your app setup look like? Any other middleware (or perhaps a proxying server in front of Node) that might cause the issue?

Comment: I agree with @robertklep. I guess its your proxy which is caching. Can you check the headers of the response if you see any cache header? Also, try setting the following headers on server side.

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0 

See if that works for you?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Answer (score 11):

Edit:
Notice that express sets view cache enabled for production:
see [express docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html)

> view cache Enables view template compilation caching, enabled in
> production by default

Try adding this line in your app config section:

```
app.disable('view cache');
```

Also, try adding cache-control headers

```
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
res.render('articles/show', {
...
```

From [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) docs:

> **Cahce-Control**
>
> The Cache-Control general-header field is used to specify directives
> that MUST be obeyed by all caching mechanisms along the
> request/response chain. The directives specify behavior intended to
> prevent caches from adversely interfering with the request or
> response. These directives typically override the default caching
> algorithms. Cache directives are unidirectional in that the presence
> of a directive in a request does not imply that the same directive is
> to be given in the response.

If you need a more advanced control, consider other fields like max-age, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache) is also a good resource, you'll see that different browsers may implement this rfc slightly different.

Comment: Browser caching isn't the issue. Say I look at four different blog posts. After a bit, all URLs will start delivering the same blog post. It's like jade is caching the template and not bothering to use the object I pass to it... It just uses the last known values.

Comment: Ok, I see your point, the header is not just for Browser cache, imagine you have a Varnish in production, or your DNS has a cache mechanism like Cloudflare, this header in the response must be obeyed along the chain. But I see your point.  
Then I would replace jade for hbs or other to discard that is a template engine problem. Or have a look in the Jade repo to see if there are known issues with cache.

Comment: Yeah I think I will have to go that route.

Comment: Follow up: I ended up just going with [doT](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: try

```
let articleId;
```

instead of

```
var articleId;
```

I'm just another newbro to Node.js, but I've just solved the same issue by substituting "var" keyword for "let". The thing is that "var" creates a variable scoped by a function, while "let" – a scoped to the current block one. It is re-created every time the block is executed, which is important due to asynchronous nature of Node.js.