# Difference between no-cache and must-revalidate for Cache-Control?

Tags: caching, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

From the RFC 2616

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1

> no-cache
>
> If the no-cache directive does not specify a field-name, then a cache
>   MUST NOT use the response to satisfy a subsequent request without
>   successful revalidation with the origin server. This allows an origin
>   server to prevent caching even by caches that have been configured to
>   return stale responses to client requests.

So it directs agents to revalidate *all* responses.

Compared this to

> must-revalidate
>
> When the must-revalidate directive is present in a response received
>   by a cache, that cache MUST NOT use the entry after it becomes stale
>   to respond to a subsequent request without first revalidating it with
>   the origin server

So it directs agents to revalidate *stale* responses.

Particularly with regard to `no-cache`, is this how user agents actually, empirically treat this directive?

What's the point of `no-cache` if there's `must-revalidate` and `max-age`?

See this comment:

http://palpapers.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/

> no-cache
>
> Though this directive sounds like it is instructing the browser not to
>   cache the page, there’s a subtle difference. The “no-cache” directive,
>   according to the RFC, tells the browser that it should revalidate with
>   the server before serving the page from the cache. Revalidation is a
>   neat technique that lets the application conserve band-width. If the
>   page the browser has cached has not changed, the server just signals
>   that to the browser and the page is displayed from the cache. Hence,
>   the browser (in theory, at least), stores the page in its cache, but
>   displays it only after revalidating with the server. In practice, IE
>   and Firefox have started treating the no-cache directive as if it
>   instructs the browser not to even cache the page. We started observing
>   this behavior about a year ago. We suspect that this change was
>   prompted by the widespread (and incorrect) use of this directive to
>   prevent caching.

Has anyone got anything more official on this?

*Update*

> The must-revalidate directive ought to be used by servers if and only if failure to validate a request on the representation could result in incorrect operation, such as a silently unexecuted financial transaction.

That's something I've never taken to heart until now. The RFC is saying not to use must-revalidate lightly. The thing is, with web services, you have to take a negative view and assume the worst for your unknown client apps. Any stale resource has the potential to cause a problem.

And something else I've just considered, without Last-Modified or ETags, the browser can only fetch the whole resource again. However with ETags, I've observed that Chrome at least seems to revalidate on every request. Which makes both these directives moot or at least poorly named since they can't properly revalidate unless the request also includes other headers that then cause 'always revalidate' anyway.

I just want to make that last point clearer. By just setting `must-revalidate` but not including either an ETag or Last-Modified, the agent can only get the content again since it has nothing to send to the server to compare.

However, my empirical testing has shown that when ETag or modified header data is included in responses, the agents always revalidate anyway, regardless of the presence of the `must-revalidate` header.

So the point of `must-revalidate` is to force a 'bypass cache' when it goes stale, which can only happen when you have set a lifetime/age, thus if `must-revalidate` is set on a response with no age or other headers, it effectively becomes equivalent to `no-cache` since the response will be considered immediately stale.

-- So I'm going to finally mark Gili's answer!

Comment: So in theory the difference is _validate-always_ vs _validate-if-stale_, whereas in practice no-cache gets treated by certain browsers as the comment you quoted says as _never-validate_ … so you should make your choice of which of those to use based on what caching behavior you actually want to achieve in practice …

Comment: Please read

  http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-latest.html

and see whether this clarifies things for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Cache-Control: max-age=0 and no-cache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache)

Comment: check this decision tree for answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925190/3748498

Answer (score 246, accepted):

`must-revalidate` means:

> The browser may use stale cache entries if and only if the server confirms that they are still valid (using [conditional requests](https://ieftimov.com/posts/conditional-http-get-fastest-requests-need-no-response-body/)).

Whereas `no-cache` means:

> `must-revalidate` plus the fact that server responses becomes stale right away.

If a server response is cacheable for 10 seconds, then `must-revalidate` kicks in after 10 seconds, while `no-cache` kicks in immediately.

And finally, **`max-age: 0` should no longer be used**.

My interpretation is based on [RFC 7234](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.2) and [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#force_revalidation). The latter reads:

> It is often stated that the combination of `max-age=0` and `must-revalidate` has the same meaning as `no-cache`.

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

> `max-age=0` means that the response is immediately stale, and `must-revalidate` means that it must not be reused without revalidation once it is stale — so, in combination, the semantics seem to be the same as `no-cache`.
> However, that usage of `max-age=0` is a remnant of the fact that many implementations prior to HTTP/1.1 were unable to handle the `no-cache` directive — and so to deal with that limitation, `max-age=0` was used as a workaround.
> But now that HTTP/1.1-conformant servers are widely deployed, there's no reason to ever use that `max-age=0` and must-revalidate combination — you should instead just use `no-cache`.

Comment: That's how I'm seeing it now. The interesting part is my last para, without an ETag or Last-Modified, the agent has nothing to use to validate what it has in cache and must download the whole payload again. So when the RFC says "revalidate" that probably means, re-fetch.

Comment: Which also means `max-age=0, must-revalidate` and `no-cache` are identical

Comment: @Anshul, at first I thought you were right that 'max-age=0, must-revalidate and no-cache are identical', but see Jeffrey Fox's answer which seems to indicate that's not quite right.

Comment: @DonHatch added my comments below in Jeffrey's answer.

Comment: @Anshul No, `must-revalidate` and `no-cache` have different meaning for fresh responses: If a cached response is fresh (i.e, the response hasn't expired), `must-revalidate` will make the proxy serve it right away without revalidating with the server, whereas with `no-cache` the proxy must revalidate the cached response regardless of freshness. Source: "HTTP - The Definitive Guide", pages 182-183.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun, exactly, and that is why `max-age=0` is needed to make `must-revalidate` behave identical to `no-cache`

Comment: @Anshul Oh, I thought you meant that *all three of them* are identical.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun Ah, I can see the source of confusion. May be I should have written _`no-cache` and `max-age=0, must-revalidate` are identical_

Comment: @Anshul Not quite identical according to RFC7234: "in all circumstances a cache MUST obey the **must-revalidate** directive; in particular, if a cache cannot reach the origin server for any reason, it MUST generate a **504 (Gateway Timeout)** response." But **no-cache** is less draconian (no 5xx server error) and may serve a stale resource if for instance a cache cannot connect to the origin server.

Comment: @Anshul But Mozilla states that **Cache-Control: max-age=0** may serve stale resources. I'm going to guess that every caching agent may implement the RFC slightly differently.

Comment: @ClintPachl What Mozilla states does not contradict what Anshul wrote. Mozilla is telling you that so long as you omit `must-revalidate` they may return stale results. If you don't want stale results, make sure to include it.

Comment: `no-cache` should be called `always-revalidate`

Answer (score 28):

`max-age=0, must-revalidate` and `no-cache` aren't exactly identical. With `must-revalidate`, if the server doesn't respond to a revalidation request, the browser/proxy is supposed to return a 504 error. With `no-cache`, it would just show the cached content, which would be probably preferred by the user (better to have something stale than nothing at all). This is why `must-revalidate` is intended for critical transactions only.

Comment: Not sure about your `no-cache` interpretation. From the [RFC 7234](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.2) _The "no-cache" response directive indicates that the response MUST NOT be used to satisfy a subsequent request without successful validation on the origin server. This allows an origin server to prevent a cache from using it to satisfy a request without contacting it, even by caches that have been configured to send stale responses._

This sounds similar to restrictions for `must-revalidate`

Comment: Does Jeffrey have evidence that implementations behave how he has described?

Comment: I think this answer is correct for proxy / lb servers. But indeed, browsers don't return a 504 in that case.

Comment: So `must-validate` means `must-refresh`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control directly states "`no-cache` and `max-age=0, must-revalidate` indicates same meaning."

Answer (score 22):

With Jeffrey Fox's interpretation about `no-cache`, i've tested under chrome 52.0.2743.116 m, the result shows that `no-cache` has the same behavior as `must-revalidate`, they all will **NOT** use local cache when server is unreachable, and, they all will use cache while tap browser's Back/Forward button when server is unreachable.
As above, i think `max-age=0, must-revalidate` is identical to `no-cache`, at least in implementation.

Comment: Will Chrome use local cache when the server is available to revalidate? (i.e. "If-Modified-Since"). In both cases?

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, [the MDN page on HTTP validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#validation) directly addresses this (emphasis mine):

> It is often stated that the combination of `max-age=0` and
> `must-revalidate` has the same meaning as `no-cache`.
>
> ```
> Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
> ```
>
> `max-age=0` means that the
> response is immediately stale, and `must-revalidate` means that it must
> not be reused without revalidation once it is stale — so in
> combination, the semantics seem to be the same as `no-cache`.
>
> However, that usage of `max-age=0` is a remnant of the fact that many
> implementations prior to HTTP/1.1 were unable to handle the `no-cache`
> directive — and so to deal with that limitation, `max-age=0` was used as
> a workaround.
>
> **But now that HTTP/1.1-conformant servers are widely deployed, there's
> no reason to ever use that `max-age=0`-and-`must-revalidate` combination —
> you should instead just use `no-cache`.**

For reference (for our own personal cache control, heh) that MDN page was last updated on June 1, 2022; and I pulled that quote on June 10, 2022 ([archive June 8](https://web.archive.org/web/20220608065931/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)).

Comment: Great explanation, and so typical for us devs to forget about the ancient compatibility reasons of old... in our SlickStack (LEMP) project, for dynamic content e.g. WordPress pages, we set `nocache` but enable server-side Nginx FastCGI caching, and for static files we set `public, max-age=691200` which might also be overwritten by CDNs like Cloudflare.

Comment: It says "there's no reason" to use one over the other, but doesn't directly say that they have identical behaviour. In particular, is there a difference as to whether clients will use "If-Modified-Since" requests? I think this text leaves that possibility open

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with part of @Jeffrey Fox's answer:

> max-age=0, must-revalidate and no-cache aren't exactly identical.

Not agreed with this part:

> With no-cache, it would just show the cached content, which would be probably preferred by the user (better to have something stale than nothing at all).

What should implementations do when `cache-control: no-cache` revalidation failed is just not specified in the RFC document. It's all up to implementations. They may throw a 504 error like `cache-control: must-revalidate` or just serve a stale copy from cache.

Answer (score -2):

I think there is a difference between `max-age=0, must-revalidate` and `no-cache`:

In the `must-revalidate` case the client is allowed to send a `If-Modified-Since` request and serve the response from cache if `304 Not Modified` is returned.

In the `no-cache` case, the client must not cache the response, so should not use `If-Modified-Since`.

Comment: But `no-cache` does not mean `no-store` - with `no-cache`, the resource can still be cached in the client; it just must be re-validated before being used?

Comment: You are conflating `no-cache` and `no-store`. `no-cache` means the resource MUST be **revalidated**. **Revalidate** includes the option to use conditional requests, such as `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since`.

Comment: @JulesRandolph: you may be right. Do you have any tests / demos? All the conflicting evidence-free assertions on this q are frustrating. Even the accepted answer just says "At least, that's my interpretation". I might set up a test bed and post it here if I get some time.

Comment: I'm wrong was a bug on my end.