# How to enable HTTP caching for the resource handler with Spring MVC and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching, spring-security

I wish to enable HTTP caching for some static resources such as images, for which access is restricted by Spring Security. (These resources are not security critical, but shouldn't be publicly accessible either). How do I avoid having Spring Security add HTTP response headers that disable caching?

If I add `setCachePeriod()` into my resource handler registration in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addResourceHandlers()` as following:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
  .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/").setCachePeriod(3600);
```

The resources are still returned with following headers that disable caching:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 04 Aug 2014 07:45:36 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
```

I want to avoid introducing any XML configuration into the project, which currently uses only Java annotation configuration.

Are there better solutions than extending the Spring resource handler?

Comment: Even overwriting/implementing a resource handler will not help. Spring Security by default disables caching for secured resources. If you don't want this disable caching for those resources. This can be done using the `HttpSecurity` something like `http.antMatcher("/static/**").headers().disable()` disables all headers set by Spring Security. This is also explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#default-security-headers) in the Spring Security Reference Guide.

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum. A further problem is that the configuration already has an `antMatchers()` invocation as following: `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/static/public/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()`. How do I apply the `headers().disable()` rule to "/static/**" without overriding the above `antMatchers()` rule?

Comment: Doesn't matter, add another one or chain the multiple configs with `and()`. Something like `authenticated().and().headers().disabled()`.

Comment: I want to disable Spring Security headers for "/static/**". I understand your suggestion would disable them either for all requests, or for those matching the existing `antMatchers()` rule.

Comment: No... Your understanding isn't correct... Also you can always add an additional `antMatcher` element. They are all merged together.

Comment: According to http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#antMatcher%28java.lang.String%29 "Invoking antMatcher(String) will override previous invocations of requestMatchers(), antMatcher(String), regexMatcher(String), and requestMatcher(RequestMatcher)." and this matches my experiments. Similarly for `requestMatchers()`.

Comment: If they override you are still able to configure multiple things on it hence the `and()`. Also `/static/**` and `/static/public/**` shouldn't override (although you would have to take care in the ordering).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63858/discussion-between-samuli-karkkainen-and-m-deinum).

Comment: Did you find a working solution that can selectively disable spring security headers? I only managed to disable them all or none.

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 8):

You can use webContentInterceptor resource to allow static resource caching.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/static/*"/>
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="31556926"/>
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </bean>
   </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Using annotations to configure cache interceptors is done following way.
In your web config class you can add a bean for `WebContentInterceptor` class and add it into interceptors list.

```
@Bean
public WebContentInterceptor webContentInterceptor() {
    WebContentInterceptor interceptor = new WebContentInterceptor();
    interceptor.setCacheSeconds(31556926);
    interceptor.setUseExpiresHeader(true);;
    interceptor.setUseCacheControlHeader(true);
    interceptor.setUseCacheControlNoStore(true);
    return interceptor;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(webContentInterceptor());
}
```

Refer [this site](http://g00glen00b.be/spring-websockets-config/) to see how it's done.

Comment: It appears that Spring Security sets its caching-prevention headers after these interceptors have ran, so the code in your example has no effect with Spring Security.

Comment: Need `addPathPatterns("/static/*")` as well

Comment: This is all deprecated now. What is the new approach?

Comment: This is the new approach:

WebContentInterceptor interceptor = new WebContentInterceptor();
interceptor.setCacheControl(CacheControl.youNeeds());
registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);

Answer (score 1):

Spring 4 documentation has this solution, "If you actually want to cache specific responses, your application can selectively invoke `HttpServletResponse.setHeader(String,String)`
to override the header set by Spring Security". This is useful to ensure things like CSS, JavaScript, and images are properly cached.

Below snippet can be used for springmvc configuration,

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
        .setCachePeriod(31556926);
  }

// ...
}
```

For reference:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-cache-control

Comment: This does override the `max-age` part of the `Cache-Control` header. However it doesn't remove the `must-revalidate` part of that header, nor the `Pragma: no-cache` header.

Comment: Other option mentioned in doc is setting header directly, 
HttpServletResponse.setHeader(String,String)

Comment: Where do you propose calling setHeader()? I've tried various places, and every time Spring Security overrides the headers. Is installing my own servlet filter the only way?

Comment: Just tried it and does not seems to work,My bad.It seems to be an open issue  https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2728

Comment: I just tried the solution mentioned here. Worked beautifully.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530575/disable-caching-for-specific-url-in-spring-security/30949227#30949227

Answer (score 0):

You are already setup for caching.  [must-revalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148884/difference-between-no-cache-and-must-revalidate) means once the cache expires (3600 seconds) do not use it anymore so your response headers, i think, are correct for what you want.

Comment: Good point that `must-revalidate` doesn't prevent caching. However the `must-revalidate` semantics isn't what one typically wants, and `Pragma: no-cache` often prevents caching anyway.