# Python code structure with flask integrated

Tags: python, flask

[Newbie] I have written a python program that does some data manipulations to imported xlsx files and save them as csv. It looks kinda like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7    

def main():

    imported_files = import_files_from_input_folder('/input/*.xlsx')

    data_handling_functions(imported_files)

    save_processed_files_to_output_folder('/output/')

if __name__ = '__main__':

    main()
```

I want to create a web app (using flask) for the users to use the program, by uploading their files to 'input' folder, and then download the results from 'output' folder. Thanks to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628053/uploading-and-downloading-files-with-flask) and some others, I know how to upload multiple files into 'input' folder.

Now, my first question is: how to list all the files in 'output' folder and let users download them?

My second question is: how to wrap/integrate the flask part into the existed program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how a basic Flask web server looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

so it is quite straightforward to integrate your functionality inside the app. Just add a routing function (like the hello) and call the functions you would normally call inside the main in your code, and after that render the results on a web page, along with some Download buttons. For this you could use the function `render_template` and give the output (altered in such a way that it can be iterated over to get each file) as a parameter, like so:

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('name_of_template', output = your_output)
```

You can find Flask documentation [here](http://flask.pocoo.org) and it will show you how to do all that.
I recommend that you use the jinja2 API to add Python code to your HTML templates e.g. you could do something like that:

```
{% for file in output %}
    <!-- Output file inside html tag -->
    <!-- Add a download button -->
{% endfor %}
```

You can find more about Jinja [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/)

And of course, you would store the CSVs on your server.