# Cache-control max-age setting using .htaccess

Tags: http, caching, http-headers

This is my http.confg file:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(xml)$">
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
Header set Cache-Control "max-age= 300, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

This is the link I'm experimenting on : `
http://ec2-54-226-158-192.compute-1.amazonaws.com/LiveTV.xml

**(1) When I first direct to this link on Mozilla Firefox,**

this is what I listen on the server side:
[image]

and this is what I gather on the client side, using wire-shark.[image]

**(2) Now I send the request again:**

this is what I listen on the server side:[image]

and this is what I gather on the client side, using wire-shark.[image]

**(3) When the max-age expires, I send the request again:**

this is what I listen on the server side:
[image]

and this is what I gather on the client side, using wire-shark.
[image]

My Questions over here are :

- ***Why am I getting `Cache-Control: max-age=0` on the server side ?***
- ***Shouldn't I get 200 response after the max-age expires? Why am I getting 304 status code on the first request after max-age expires?***

Comment: Did you check `httpd.conf` file are there any cache control settings ?

Comment: @sozkul  You mean the apache2.conf ?

Comment: Yes, http server's configuration file, generally `httpd.conf`

Comment: @sozkul added it to the post on the top, kindly check it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29237792/577159  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1383359/577159