# Does no-cache allow a stale cached response to be returned?

Tags: http, caching, browser-cache, cache-control, no-cache

I'm reading contradicting statements about `no-cache` and `must-revalidate`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37741094/2063755) says:

> With must-revalidate, if the server doesn't respond to a revalidation
> request, the browser/proxy is supposed to return a 504 error. With
> no-cache, it would just show the cached content

However "just show the cached content" without revalidation contradicts what is in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.4:

> The "no-cache" request directive indicates that a cache MUST NOT use a
> stored response to satisfy the request
> without successful validation
> on the origin server.

If it's true that `no-cache` won't allow the use of a cached response without revalidation, then what is the point of `must-revalidate`?

Answer (score 1):

A cache [may serve stale responses](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.2.4):

> A "stale" response is one that either has explicit expiry information
> or is allowed to have heuristic expiry calculated, but is not fresh
> according to the calculations in Section 4.2.

Unless:

> A cache MUST NOT generate a stale response if it is prohibited by an
> explicit in-protocol directive (e.g., by a "no-store" or "no-cache"
> cache directive, a "must-revalidate" cache-response-directive, or an
> applicable "s-maxage" or "proxy-revalidate" cache-response-directive;
> see Section 5.2.2).

Note in particular that in this requirement `no-store` and `no-cache` are *cache* directives, and `must-revalidate` is a cache-*response* directive.

So, `must-revalidate` is for an origin server to indicate that a response may not be reused when it goes stale, as opposed to a way for clients to indicate that they would not accept a stale response.