# read updated data on client from file created by server JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, d3.js, browser-cache

I am creating a web application in java. On client side I have a bar chart that display some data stored in a tsv file created by the java server page. By clicking on a button the server updates these data in the file. Now I want to read the refreshed data, but I get the older ones. It seems that the browser cached the file so it can't get the changed file.

This is my servlet code:

```
public class GetDataServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private User user;
    Utility utility; 

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        reset();
    }

    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        user.getProfile().get(0).setWeigth(user.getProfile().get(0).getWeigth()+0.03);
        user.getProfile().get(1).setWeigth(user.getProfile().get(1).getWeigth()+0.02);
        user.getProfile().get(5).setWeigth(user.getProfile().get(5).getWeigth()+0.01);
        utility.createTsvFile(user, "/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/webapps/Visualizer/data.tsv");
        String message = String.format("data.tsv");
        i++;
        out.print(message);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getParameter("reset").compareTo("yes")==0)
            reset();
    }

    private void reset(){
        List<Concept> children = new ArrayList<Concept>();

        Concept food = new Concept();
        food.setWeigth(0.10);
        food.setLabel("food");
        food.setColor("#98abc5");

        Concept dish = new Concept();
        dish.setWeigth(0.08);
        dish.setLabel("dish");
        dish.setParent(food);
        dish.setColor("#8a89a6");

        Concept cuisine = new Concept();
        cuisine.setWeigth(0.06);
        cuisine.setLabel("cuisine");
        cuisine.setParent(food);
        cuisine.setColor("#8a89a6");

        children.add(dish);
        children.add(cuisine);
        food.setChildren(children);

        children.clear();

        Concept pizza = new Concept();
        pizza.setWeigth(0.05);
        pizza.setLabel("pizza");
        pizza.setParent(dish);
        pizza.setColor("#6b486b");

        Concept spaghetti = new Concept();
        spaghetti.setWeigth(0.05);
        spaghetti.setLabel("spaghetti");
        spaghetti.setParent(dish);
        spaghetti.setColor("#6b486b");

        Concept sushi = new Concept();
        sushi.setWeigth(0.06);
        sushi.setLabel("sushi");
        sushi.setParent(dish);
        sushi.setColor("#6b486b");

        children.add(pizza);
        children.add(spaghetti);
        children.add(sushi);

        dish.setChildren(children);



        List<Concept> profile = new ArrayList<Concept>();
        profile.add(food);
        profile.add(dish);
        profile.add(cuisine);
        profile.add(pizza);
        profile.add(spaghetti);
        profile.add(sushi);

        user = new User("mario", profile);
        utility = new Utility("");


    }

}
```

This is the javascript code that calls the servlet:

```
    function ajaxSyncRequest(reqURL) {
    //Creating a new XMLHttpRequest object
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //for IE6, IE5
    }
    //Create a asynchronous GET request
    xmlhttp.open("GET", reqURL, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

    //Execution blocked till server send the response
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            update(xmlhttp.responseText);
            //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        } else {
            alert('Something is wrong !!');
        }
    }
}

function update(file){
    d3.tsv(file, function(error, data) {
......
```

In the html page I have also put this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

but it doesn't work.

With this code I can display the correct data the first time I call the servlet, than even if the data in the file tsv changes I get the first one.

Which is the best way to read the refreshed data in the file?

Comment: Maybe help at   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache

Comment: I have tried no cache and max-age=0 with no resut.

Comment: You're creating the tsv file and then outputting "data.tsv" to the browser.  In other words, you are not returning the tsv file in the response.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: I have added additional information to the question. My problem is that I read the correct data only the first time I call the servlet. Then I read always these data even if they are changed in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I you are facing problem from browser caching problem like this so two hings can be done

1)You can create a filter and instruct in filter not to cache some what like this [Prevent user from seeing previously visited secured page after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-going-back-to-the-previous-secured-page-after-logout)

2)Each time you are hitting the url of tsv file add a random variable in end .(This is usually in case of internet exlorer)