# Cache-Control header - must-revalidate with different max-age value

Tags: cache-control

I want to use UrlRewriteFilter library. 
I would like to know if there is any differences between these two "Cache-Control" headers.

```
<set type="response-header" name="Cache-Control">public, must-revalidate, max-age=1</set>
```

and

```
<set type="response-header" name="Cache-Control">public, must-revalidate, max-age=604800</set>
```

1. Do these headers mean that we define any cache ?
2. Do browsers respect the max-age parameter values ?

Does the 2nd one can have an impact on the site's load speed ? 
I want to use these configuration on Jahia site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Cache-Control: max-age=0 and no-cache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache)

Comment: @Joe, thanks. So `max-age=0, must-revalidate` means `no-cache`. What about `max-age=1, must-revalidate` and `max-age=604800, must-revalidate` ? What do they mean ? And what are the differences ?