# ajax 304 not modified can't receive response

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-304

I have an API to handle cache control. Server will set response header  "last-modified" and next request from browser will have If-modified-Since header.

However, when I use ajax to request API, it will not set If-modified-Since header automatically.
And I set If-modified-Since in ajax request header, server response 304 status code. But response body is empty.

> Is ajax need to manually to fulfill browser behavior about cache control?

Is there better solution?

I find a similar question [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-fix-browser-cache-and-notmodified-respond-for-json-jquery-ajax-ifmodified-true-break-on-data-respond).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it resolved after I study [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache?rq=1).

Setting Request Header to

```
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'
```

If response provide Last-Modified header, next request will automatically set If-Modified-Since and value is equal.

When 304 response occur, response content is from browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

The response body should be empty for a 304 response, that's how it's intended to work. [The protocol](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) states:

> The 304 response MUST NOT contain a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

So, if you send the request with the `If-modified-since` and the condition is not met, you won't get a response body (the actual data). You're basically stating that you have the content and you want it only if it updated.

Try to not use the `If-Modified-Since` header and instead use the `Cache-control` header:

```
$.ajax({
...
headers: {
     'Cache-Control': 'max-age=1000' 
}
...
});
```

Comment: I have to use If-Modified-Since header to verify data which is changed or not. And by the way, where is different Cache-Control from request and response?