# Resolving contradictory Cache-Control headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, caching, restify

I am maintaining a Restify server using a static content plugin. The plugin imposes a `Cache-Control` header despite anything that happened beforehand. `max-age` is always included, and defaults to 3600.

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
```

I need to have a large `max-age` for everything except `index.html`.

```
server.pre((req, res, next) => {
    const path = url.parse(req.url);
    if (path.pathname === '/' && req.accepts('text/html')) {
        req.url = '/public/index.html';

        // Encourage the client to always download index.html.
        res.header('Expires', '0');
        res.header('Cache-Control',
            'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
    }

    next();
});
```

The problem is that the static server's forced addition of `Cache-Control`  causes the server to send contradictory `max-age` values.

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Cache-Control:public, max-age=315360000
```

I tried something to stop this that did not work, but is this even an issue? I don't know if browsers will resolve the contradiction by downloading `index.html` fresh (which is what I want)

Answer (score 0):

Quote [Michael Krebs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383359/394397):

> I believe max-age=0 simply tells caches (and user agents) the response is stale from the get-go and so they SHOULD revalidate the response (eg. with the If-Not-Modified header) before using a cached copy, whereas, no-cache tells them they MUST revalidate before using a cached copy. [From 14.9.1 What is Cacheable](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1) [...]

This quote is somewhat out of context for brevity, but the language of the spec makes `max-age` a "weaker" directive than `no-cache`, `must-revalidate`, etc. The actual behavior is still an implementation detail in browsers, but if `max-age` occurs near directives that **strongly** tell the browser to re-validate or not cache, it should be reasonable to expect that the browser will comply ([Corroborating answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/394397)).