# what does setting Cache-Control: max-age=20 in request header do?

Tags: http-headers, cache-control

When i set `Cache-Control: 'max-age=0'` in request header,this request will revalidate its cache entry (eg. with the If-Not-Modified header) all the way to the origin server. If the reply is then 304 (Not Modified), the cached entity can be used.

When i set  `Cache-Control: 'max-age=20'` in response header,It,s mean is whilein 20 s , Request at the same address will use the cache.

But if i set `Cache-Control: 'max-age=20'` in request header,It doesn't work as well as the former,So i want to know what will happen when i set max-age=xxx(xxx != 0) in request header?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a user agent set a max-age greater than zero in its request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339832/can-a-user-agent-set-a-max-age-greater-than-zero-in-its-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification tells us:

> The `max-age` request directive indicates that the client is
> unwilling to accept a response whose age is greater than the
> specified number of seconds.

So `max-age=20` means that the cache shouldn't return a cached response older than 20 seconds.

The key difference here is that the *client* is choosing the desired freshness time of the resource, while in the usual case it's the *server* determining that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I set `Cache-Control: 'max-age=5'` in request headers and set `Cache-Control: 'max-age=20'` in response headers at the same time, it means that I can,t receive the cache after 5 seconds?

Comment: But when I experimented with that, I found that I could still receive a cache of 20 seconds

Comment: @planB: I'm not sure what you mean by "receive a cache". In any case, the request header applies to entries already in the cache. The cache headers in the response are unrelated, they will only apply to future requests.