# WebPageTest shows no static cache but I got 304 response in repeated run

Tags: web, browser-cache, cache-control, webpagetest

I am testing my webpage with [webpagetest.org](https://webpagetest.org/)

On my page, there are a bunch of images. I can see them well cached in the repeated run: (304 response is marked as yellow in WebPageTest waterfall result)
[image]

However, in cache static content, there's no check on those resources
[image]

I found the difference is that those scripts and styles have `cache-control: max-age=2592000`, while those media resources have `cache-control: max-age=0` in the server response. Does it mean that WebPageTest will neglect these responses with `max-age=0` in static cache checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean that WebPageTest will neglect these responses with max-age=0 in static cache checking?

The documentation states that resources which include a specific indication of non-cacheability will not be subject to the 'Cache Static' check:

> Applicable Objects
>
> Any non-html object with a mime type of `"text/*"`, `"*javascript*"` or `"image/*"` that does not explicitly have an `Expires` header of `0` or `-1`, a `cache-control` header of `"private"`, `"no-store"` or `"no-cache"` or a pragma header of `"no-cache"`

While `max-age=0` isn't included in that list, it should be [treated the same as `no-cache`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache), and is likely being treated the same here and excluding those objects from this check.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I found the document you mentioned in the glossary section which I always skips.