# Are "max-age" and "no-cache" from "Cache-Control" header mutually exclusive?

Tags: java, spring, cache-control

Do "max-age" with a positive value and "no-cache" make sense?
The documentation doesn't mention whether they are mutually exclusive https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

However org.springframework.http.CacheControl doesn't allow me to create an instance of it which would contain both of them. It has an interface that allows you to create an instance of CacheControl that would have either "max-age" or "no-cache".

```
public static CacheControl noCache() {
    CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
    cc.noCache = true;
    return cc;
}


public static CacheControl maxAge(Duration maxAge) {
    CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
    cc.maxAge = maxAge;
    return cc;
}
```

There is no no-static method for adding "no-cache" or "max-age" after instance creation. Is it on purpose and correct?

Comment: `max-age` with a greater than 0 value will not be considered if the `no-cache` is set first. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383359/17173476) explains the difference between these two very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't make sense to use a `max-age` with a positive value when you use `no-cache`. Since `no-cache` [means](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.2) "that the response MUST NOT be used to satisfy a subsequent request without successful validation on the origin server", the freshness time set by `max-age` won't have any effect.

There's also no reason—at least according to the standard—to use `max-age=0` when using `no-cache`, though some people do it anyway, presumably due to a perceived benefit to backward compatibility.